# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

[Moderator election #6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/6) on Role-playing Games has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: nitsua60]

[image: Oblivious Sage]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/6) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5712582737395712).

Answer (score 31):

### Congratulations to both of you!

I'm looking forward to being co-mods with you (for longer than the week we were last time Nits :p).
And welcome (back) to the world of weird, wonderful (and occationally scary) tools and features.

### Also thanks to everyone else who ran

Unfortunately, a real election requires someone to not win, and I want to thank the four of you who threw your hat in. I hope you still found the endeavour worthwhile, and aren't too discouraged. There'll be elections in the future, and we'll need someone to run in those!

Comment: *7,510 voters were eligible, 1,320 visited the site during the election, 719 visited the election page, and 323 voted* - glad to be part of the "4.3% club"

Answer (score 30):

#### Our mod team is turning into quite the menagerie of creatures.

[image]

(and one humanoid, linksassin)

Congrats nitsua60 and Oblivious Sage! I have no doubt you will both do a fine job.

Comment: Maybe I need to talk to linksassin about putting some animal ears on their avatar...

Comment: @ObliviousSage Maybe we can just add a cuckoo to his avatar.

Comment: Hmmmm, [much to consider](https://www.myconfinedspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/schemer.jpg)...

Comment: [Gonna find our way home to the animal zoo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAG4kxpYcFE)

Comment: @ObliviousSage Are you sure linkasassin isn't secrety three tannuki under a coat?

Comment: @Trish Yes, because it would take at least 4 tannuki to equal 1 linksassin.